# Laravel 5.8: beberlei/assert/lib/Assert/functions.php return type produces error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I installed Laravel 5.8 on local server it works fine, but on remote server it reports the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /***/vendor/beberlei/assert/lib/Assert/functions.php on line 37

This is the line producing the error

```
function that($value, $defaultMessage = null, string $defaultPropertyPath = null): AssertionChain
{
    return Assert::that($value, $defaultMessage, $defaultPropertyPath);
}
```

I think the PHP version can't understand the return type or Scalar type string. The PHP version of the server is `7.3.13` and return type and scalar type sting are valid statement in this version but it still reports the error. Do any of you guys know why does this happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I strongly suspect your remote server is not running PHP 7.3. 7.3 may be installed, but I'd bet you have multiple versions installed (and what's on the web may differ from the CLI). Put `<?php phpinfo();` in a file in your `public` directory and see what it outputs when you visit it in a browser.

Comment: @ceejayoz I also suspected that and I did this. The PHP version is 7.3.13

Comment: To triple-check: you confirmed the PHP version **in-browser**, in the same virtualhost your Laravel app is using? Can you quadruple-check it by putting `return phpversion();` in a route? https://www.php.net/phpversion

Comment: @ceejayoz The Laravel app is in a shared host. This is the url, `http://mheidari.me/tt.php`. result of `<?php print phpversion();` is `7.3.13`.

Comment: There's no Laravel app at http://mheidari.me/, though. Different virtualhosts on a server can be configured to use different PHP versions. Is your Laravel app on a different virtualhost? If you put the `tt.php` in the Laravel app's `public` folder and visit it there, do you get the same version?

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh! you are right bro, The Laravel app is in `http://tour.mheidari.me` which is a subdomain. Thanks a lot. You saved my day. :)

Comment: This answer may help :
[Php artisan and composer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77814681/4671431)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app works when accessed via http://mheidari.me/tour.mheidari.me/public/.

Your app doesn't work when accessed via http://tour.mheidari.me/public/.

This implies your virtualhosts have different PHP versions assigned to them, and the error you're receiving would only be present in PHP versions earlier than PHP 7.