# Php artisan and composer not working after git clone

Tags: php, laravel, git, npm, composer-php

EDIT: I'm not sure if my composer or my npm got corrupted. I still don't know the answer to this problem but what I did is I did a system restore. I did the steps below again and it magically worked.

All I did was

1. Git clone
2. Composer install
3. npm install
4. npm run dev

Then boom! I can't "php artisan serve", I can't even use "laravel new" (No errors message again).

What can be the solution for this?

Btw, even the apache on XAMPP and UWAMP are closing on its own. I already tried changing the port.

[image]

Package.json:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide us a copy of your package.json as well as your php server configuration ?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you https://devmarketer.io/learn/setup-laravel-project-cloned-github-com/
If your working locally (with the artisan CLI) you don't really need to setup XAMPP or UWAMP for now.

Comment: `I can't "php artisan serve"`  - what does that mean? Why can't you call that command any more? How is this related to PHP, Git, **and** npm?

Comment: try checking the laravel logs or the PHP logs and seeing if there are any hints in there. If not then you will have to sprinkle `dd('something')` around your code to try to figure out where it crashes. Occasional culprits are permission issues or very low memory configuration for PHP

Answer (score 0):

i once faced this issue. my problem was missing .env file. Make sure you have an .env file in your project and key in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem with running artisan

**Solution:**

1. clear bootstrap/cache folder
2. run `composer dumpautoload`

You fine!

PS:
i got this issue when i was working on git with another programmer... it was becase my Cache folder inside Bootsrtap folder was not listed on my .gitignore file. As you can see here is the error i got when i was running `php artisan serve` :

```
PHP Warning:  require(XXX\vendor\composer/../beberlei/assert/lib/Assert/functions.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in XXX\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 41
```